# Stack overflow c++ (где моя память?)

Tags: c++, функции, рекурсия

Пишу программу для реверса символов в предложении (с помощью рекурсивной функции, обязательно). При первом же входе в функцию VS начинает орать о перегрузке стека. Увеличил объем с 1мб до 4х для этого проекта - не помогает.

**Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x011E5B89 в Project1.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (параметры: 0x00000001, 0x01202FD4).
Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x011E5B89 в Project1.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (параметры: 0x00000001, 0x01202FD4).**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>


using namespace std;

int textreverse(int fi, char rtext[10]);

int main()
{
SetConsoleCP(1251);// установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток ввода
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток вывода

int strln, i, si;
char refstring[10], resstring[10];
cout << "Введите предложение до 100 символов, где последний символ - точка:" << endl;
cin >> refstring;

strln = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    if (refstring[i] == '.') {
        strln = i + 1;
        break;
    }
}

if (strln != 0) {
    if (refstring[0] != '.') {
        textreverse(0, refstring);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Ошибка! Первый символ стоки - точка!" << endl;
    }
}
else {
    cout << "Ошибка! В строке нет точки!" << endl;
}

system("pause"); 
return 0;
}

int textreverse(int fi, char rtext[10])
{
if (rtext[fi] != '.') {
    textreverse(fi++, rtext);
}
else {
    cout << rtext[fi];
}

cout << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело не только в стеке. Смотрите:

```
char refstring[10], resstring[10];
cout << "Введите предложение до 100 символов, где последний символ - точка:" << endl;
cin >> refstring;
```

В `refstring` у вас вносится **одно слово**, до пробела, а не строка, причем вы запрашиваете до 100 символов, а вносите в массив из 10 байт, так что слово в 10 символов уже вызовет проблемы.

Дальше у вас некорректно считается `strln` - если точки нет (а ее скорее всего нет), это нуль.

Да и сама функция обращения строки вызывает сомнения в ее адекватности (хотя внимательно я ее не смотрел).

Я бы делал так:

```
void reverse(char * text, int first, int last)
{
    if (first >= last) return;
    char tmp = text[first];
    text[first] = text[last];
    text[last] = tmp;
    reverse(text,first+1,last-1);
}
```

У вас в функции идет рекурсивный вызов

```
textreverse(fi++, rtext);
```

т.е. вы вызываете ее с тем же значением 0, что и остальные вызовы - ведь `++` у вас постфиксный! Вызывайте как

```
textreverse(fi+1, rtext);
```

Правда, и при этом работать она не станет, но бесконечной рекурсии не будет...

Но все указанные вначале ошибки исправьте тоже :)

Comment: я запрашивал из 100 изначально (до этого размерность была иная). Меня в данном случае пока что не интересуют пробелы. Единственный индикатор конца строки - точка (по условию данной мне задачи), да и с пробелами я еще не пробовал вводить данные. Я подозреваю, что VS не понимает условия выхода из рекурсии, потому и ругается, а как ему объяснить когда выходить - не знаю

Comment: См. дополненный ответ

Comment: Спасибо, воспользовался советами. Но теперь встрял в историю:
        char * refstring;
 cin >> refstring;
ругается на ввод

Comment: Ну, а память выделить не пытались? **Куда** вы пишете, если в `refstring` - какой-то мусор вместо указателя на выделенную память? А еще лучше - ну C++ же у вас - воспользоваться `string s; getline(cin,s);`?

Comment: разобрался, спасибо. Всего вам доброго :)